# error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file. ...visual studio 2015 > intel visual Fortran compiler > console application project

Tags: visual-studio, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am running a `visual studio 2015 > intel visual Fortran compiler > console application` project .so I added these files. I want to get DLLs and call them from somewhere else.(maybe I must use another type of visual Fortran compiler projects, I am not sure)

I only make an empty consol application of visual Fortran compiler ,then add my .f90 Fortran files.and then run the project.so I got errors.maybe another routine must be done.

```
alloc_after_mesh.f90     arint3D.f90
baric.f90                blomamor.f90             blomamorc.f90            blomamorp.f90
bloseg3D.f90             bloseg3Dc.f90            calindc.f90              calprebloqueo.f90
calvnoru.f90             cg.f90                   cgrevcom.f90             comprobaciones.f90
conlud.f90               creamake.dat             derff.f90                ef_el.f90
electrostatica3D.f90     endat3D.f90              ensacmor.f90             funciones3D.f90
gauspp.f90               leema3D.f90              leetmp.f90               Makefile
Makefile.windows         matlap_orto.f90          matriz3D_orto.f90        matvec.f90
modulos_electros3D.f90   mod_mcambio.f90          norl2_3D.f90             [object]
principal.f90            procb1.f90               procb2.f90               psolve.f90
punto1.f90               readxml.f90              reslud.f90               semi3D.f90
stoptest2.f90            wrtcmp.f90               wrtcmpv.f90
```

but when compiling I got these **errors**:

what should I do, any help will be appreciated.

**updated #1**
my `Makefile.windows` is as below:

```
#################################################################
# Makefile created using the tool 'Creamake'
# 
# Creamake is distributed under the GNU GPL license
# Author: Francisco Pena, fran.pena@usc.es
# Download page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/creamake/
#################################################################

#################################################################
# User-modifiable options
#################################################################

# SOURCE AND COMMONS FOLDERS (separated by spaces)
dir_fuentes = . ..\other\blas ..\other\basicmod ..\other\common ..\other\fem \
..\other\unv ..\other\xml ..\other\vtu ..\other\conver3d

# OBJECT AND .MOD FOLDER
dir_objetos = object

# MAIN SOURCE FILE (include relative path from folder where Makefile is)
condir_principal = .\principal.f90

# EXECUTABLE NAME 
ejecutable = ..\..\solvers\electrostatics3d.exe

# NEEDED TO convert ejecutable THE DEFAULT RULE: 
$(ejecutable): $(condir_principal) 

# MODULES
modulos = comprobaciones.f90 mod_mcambio.f90 modulos_electros3D.f90 \
module_ALLOC_char_r1.f90 module_ALLOC.f90 module_ALLOC_int_alloc_r2.f90 \
module_ALLOC_int_r1.f90 module_ALLOC_int_r2.f90 module_ALLOC_log_r2.f90 \
module_ALLOC_real_alloc_r2.f90 module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r1.f90 \
module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r2.f90 module_ALLOC_real_r1.f90 \
module_ALLOC_real_r2.f90 module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.f90 module_CONVERS.f90 \
module_FILES.f90 module_REPORT.f90 module_SO_DEPENDANT.f90 defines.f90 mesh.f90 \
subdomains.f90 vector.f90 module_fem_extract_complex.f90 module_fem_extract.f90 \
module_fem_extract_real.f90 module_bsearch.f90 module_cells.f90 \
module_dataset_2411.f90 module_dataset_2412.f90 module_dataset_2467.f90 \
module_dataset.f90 module_FE_DB.f90 module_groups.f90 module_mesh.f90 \
module_readUNV.f90 module_unv.f90 module_xml_parser.f90 LIB_VTK_IO.f90 \
LIB_VTK_IO_READ.f90 module_writeVTU.f90 module_conver3d.f90 \
module_conver3d_source.f

# DEPENDENCIAS ENTRE MODULOS
# si pru1 depende de pru2... pru1.o: pru2.o
comprobaciones.obj: mesh.obj modulos_electros3D.obj modulos_electros3D.obj \
modulos_electros3D.obj modulos_electros3D.obj modulos_electros3D.obj \
modulos_electros3D.obj modulos_electros3D.obj modulos_electros3D.obj \
modulos_electros3D.obj
mod_mcambio.obj: modulos_electros3D.obj
modulos_electros3D.obj:
module_ALLOC_char_r1.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC.obj: module_ALLOC_int_r1.obj module_ALLOC_int_r2.obj \
module_ALLOC_int_alloc_r2.obj module_ALLOC_real_r1.obj module_ALLOC_real_r2.obj \
module_ALLOC_real_alloc_r2.obj module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r1.obj \
module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r2.obj module_ALLOC_char_r1.obj module_ALLOC_log_r2.obj
module_ALLOC_int_alloc_r2.obj: module_ALLOC_int_r1.obj
module_ALLOC_int_r1.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_int_r2.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_log_r2.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_real_alloc_r2.obj: module_ALLOC_real_r1.obj
module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r1.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_real_DOUBLE_r2.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_real_r1.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_ALLOC_real_r2.obj: module_REPORT.obj
module_CONVERS.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_REPORT.obj
module_FILES.obj: module_REPORT.obj module_CONVERS.obj
module_REPORT.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_SO_DEPENDANT.obj
module_SO_DEPENDANT.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj
defines.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj
mesh.obj: defines.obj
subdomains.obj: defines.obj
vector.obj: defines.obj
module_fem_extract.obj: module_fem_extract_real.obj \
module_fem_extract_complex.obj
module_dataset_2411.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_ALLOC.obj \
module_dataset.obj module_mesh.obj
module_dataset_2412.obj: module_ALLOC.obj module_dataset.obj module_mesh.obj \
module_FE_DB.obj module_cells.obj
module_dataset_2467.obj: module_dataset.obj module_mesh.obj module_cells.obj \
module_groups.obj
module_dataset.obj: module_REPORT.obj module_CONVERS.obj
module_FE_DB.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj
module_groups.obj: module_ALLOC.obj
module_mesh.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_ALLOC.obj module_FILES.obj
module_readUNV.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_SO_DEPENDANT.obj \
module_CONVERS.obj module_unv.obj module_mesh.obj
module_unv.obj: module_ALLOC.obj module_FILES.obj module_mesh.obj \
module_dataset_2411.obj module_dataset_2412.obj module_dataset_2467.obj \
module_bsearch.obj
module_xml_parser.obj: module_ALLOC.obj module_CONVERS.obj module_REPORT.obj \
module_FILES.obj
LIB_VTK_IO_READ.obj: LIB_VTK_IO.obj
module_writeVTU.obj: LIB_VTK_IO.obj
module_conver3d.obj: module_COMPILER_DEPENDANT.obj module_conver3d_source.obj

# INCLUDES
includes = 

# COMPILER
FC = gfortran

# COMPILER OPTIONS
FFLAGS = -J$(dir_objetos) -ffree-line-length-0 -ffixed-line-length-0

# LINKER OPTIONS
LDFLAGS = -static

#################################################################
# Non-modifiable part
#################################################################

# CARPETAS DE BUSQUEDA
VPATH =   $(subst ,:,$(strip $(dir_fuentes)))
vpath %.obj $(dir_objetos)

# FUENTES
fuentes_       = $(filter %.f %.F %.for %.FOR %.f90 %.F90 %.f95 %.F95 %.f03 %.F03,$(shell dir /b $(dir_fuentes)))
fuentes        = $(filter-out $(notdir $(condir_principal)) $(modulos),$(fuentes_))

# OBJETOS
modulos_obj    = $(addsuffix .obj,$(basename $(modulos)))
fuentes_obj    = $(addsuffix .obj,$(basename $(fuentes)))

# OBJETOS EN SU CARPETA
condir_modulos_obj    = $(addprefix $(dir_objetos)/,$(modulos_obj))
condir_fuentes_obj    = $(addprefix $(dir_objetos)/,$(fuentes_obj))

# OPCIONES DE COMPILACION
FFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(dir_fuentes))
FFLAGS += -I$(dir_objetos)

# REGLA PRINCIPAL
all: $(ejecutable)

$(ejecutable): $(includes) $(modulos_obj) $(fuentes_obj)
    $(FC) -o $(ejecutable) $(FFLAGS) $(condir_principal) $(condir_modulos_obj) $(condir_fuentes_obj) $(LDFLAGS)

# REGLA PARA LAS FUENTES
$(fuentes_obj): $(includes) $(modulos_obj)

# PATRONES DE REGLAS
%.obj:%.f
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $<
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 
%.obj:%.F
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $< 
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 
%.obj:%.for
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $< 
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 
%.obj:%.FOR
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $< 
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 
%.obj:%.f90
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $< 
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 
%.obj:%.F90
    $(FC) -c -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $< 
    @copy $@ $(dir_objetos) 
    @del $@ 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    del $(dir_objetos)\*.obj      
    del $(dir_objetos)\*.mod    
    del $(ejecutable)
```

**updated #2**:I updated my vs to `vs2015` to `vs2015 update3` .but I got new errors as below

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\comprobaciones.f90    1   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MESH]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\comprobaciones.f90    7   
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MESH_READ_ARRAY_UNFORMATTED]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\comprobaciones.f90    203 
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [MESH_ERROR_STRING]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\comprobaciones.f90    206 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [TRIM]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\comprobaciones.f90    206 
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   1   
Error       error #6580: Name in only-list does not exist.   [IOSTAT_END]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   19  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_COMPILER_DEPENDANT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   19  
Error       error #6580: Name in only-list does not exist.   [CONVER3D]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   24  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_CONVER3D]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   24  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [IOSTAT_END]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   89  
Error       error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [CONVER3D]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   90  
Error       error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [CONVER3D]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leema3D.f90   170 
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    1   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_CONVERS]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    9   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [LIB_VTK_IO_READ]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    10  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [LCASE]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    19  
Error       error #6608: In a CASE statement, the case-expr must be of type INTEGER, CHARACTER, or LOGICAL.   [LCASE]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    19  
Error       error #6611: The case-value must be of the same type as the case-expr.   ['mff']        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    20  
Error       error #6611: The case-value must be of the same type as the case-expr.   ['vtu']        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    31  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [VTK_INI_XML_READ]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    33  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [VTK_VAR_XML_READ]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    36  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [VTK_END_XML_READ]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\leetmp.f90    38  
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 1   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_WRITEVTU]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 29  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [COMPROBACIONES]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 30  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_CONVERS]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 31  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_FEM_EXTRACT]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 32  
Error       error #6580: Name in only-list does not exist.   [CONVER3D]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 33  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_CONVER3D]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 33  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [LIB_VTK_IO_READ]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 34  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_READUNV]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 35  
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_COMPILER_DEPENDANT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 36  
Error       error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [REAL64]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 41  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [COMPRUEBA]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 54  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [ERROR_UNIT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 55  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [OUTPUT_UNIT]        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 58  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [BLOCKING_NODE]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 64  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [LCASE]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 76  
Error       error #6608: In a CASE statement, the case-expr must be of type INTEGER, CHARACTER, or LOGICAL.   [LCASE]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 76  
Error       error #6611: The case-value must be of the same type as the case-expr.   ['mfm']        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 77  
Error       error #6611: The case-value must be of the same type as the case-expr.   ['mum']        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 80  
Error       error #6611: The case-value must be of the same type as the case-expr.   ['unv']        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 83  
Error       error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [CONVER3D]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\principal.f90 85  
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   1   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_SO_DEPENDANT]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   7   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_REPORT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   8   
Error       error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MODULE_XML_PARSER]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   9   
Error       error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [DOUBLE]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   24  
Error       error #6683: A kind type parameter must be a compile-time constant.   [DOUBLE]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   25  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [REPORT_STDOUT]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   29  
Error       error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [FOPEN]      C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   39  
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   58  
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   66  
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   77  
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   85  
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   110 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   118 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   129 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   137 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   201 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   208 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   221 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   228 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   251 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   258 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   271 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   278 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   301 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   308 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   321 
Error       error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [INT]     C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   328 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   348 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   350 
Error       error #6632: Keyword arguments are invalid without an explicit interface.   [REALLOC]       C:\Users\admin\documents\maxfem test for ifort A\maxfem_0.3.4_source\maxfem_0.3.4_source\sources\electrostatics3d\readxml.f90   352
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved as I include other related sub code directories to my project.including .f and .f90 files.
I see console that execute my project in command line environment.